Does anyone here run Mathematica on Fedora Silverblue?
Or Kinoite, or any of the other atomic desktops? My main questions are these:

The default installation writes binaries and symlinks to many directories, such as /usr/local/ and /usr/bin/, that are not writable in Silverblue. And, from what I understand, layering only applies to packages in RPM repositories. Does this mean that system-wide integration of wolframscript will be problematic in Silverblue?

Would anything be different if I installed Mathematica in my home directory, which is guaranteed not to be over-written during rpm-ostree updates? Would the installer.sh file still need sudo?

Is there a different recommended location for installation on atomic desktops? Should Mathematica go into a toolbx?

Are there are general pain points I should be aware of before making the switch to atomic desktops?


Thanks in advance.

you could try to install on vm first

I tend to do a per-user installation of Mathematica/Wolfram on most of my machines. There is no need to run the installation script with sudo when doing so.  Don't know about WolframScript, I don't normally install it.
